# ListItem.ValueSelector has some sort of onselectedIndexchange?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

I'm writing a small game and in the settings it uses a `ListItem.ValueSelector` in the settings, i'd like to if it's possible attach some event on it like with a mouse area, ie:

```
MouseArea {
anchors.fill: parent
onClicked: {
    //do something when clicked 
    }
}
```

an event that triggers when the `selectedIndex:` property in changes a `ListItem.ValueSelector`, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QML, any `property` defined should produce a corresponding `on<Property>Changed` callback.  Keeping in mind that it will capitalize the first letter of the property, a `selectedIndex` property should provide an `onSelectedIndexChanged` callback.